# Callback function in Swift to return value during JSON task

Tags: json, swift, callback

I asked this question which was closed yesterday and I was provided a similar question with how to implement call back. I am still struggling with this and have updated my code to try and use it but I seem to be running into an array of problems. All that I am trying to do is **return the value of results** as an `Array` so that I can easily manipulate it later. Is there a better/easier way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

The function takes a parameter of an array from the previous view, and uses some of the values to push to the endpoint. The resulting. JSON is what I am trying to get as an array. Current error is of course results is not defined when called in `ViewDidLoad`

**EDIT**:
results looks like:

```
["BRLBGN": 0.4699, "BGNBRL": 2.1691]
```

In **ViewDidLoad**:

```
calculateRate(value: codesToConvert, completionHandler: results)
```

In the **function**:

```
func calculateRate(value: [String], completionHandler: (_ results: [String: Any])->()){

    let url = URL(string: "domain.com")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "pairs=\(value[0] + value[2])&pairs=\(value[2]+value[0])"
    print(postString)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        do  {
            let jsonResult = try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
            let results = jsonResult as! [String: Any]
            completionHandler(results)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? And what is the JSON that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're getting proper result in `calculateRate` method, call the method `calculateRate(value:completionHandler:)` like so,

```
var arrayResults = [String:Any]()

calculateRate(value: ["a", "b", "c"]) {(results) in
    arrayResults = results
}
```

`completionHandler` is a **closure**. So, when calling `calculateRate`, you need to pass a *closure* there accepts a parameter `results` of type `[String:Any]`.

**Edit:**

Also add **`@escaping`** with `completionHandler` in the `calculateRate(value:completionHandler:)` method's signature.

```
func calculateRate(value: [String], completionHandler: @escaping (_ results: [String: Any])->()){
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I get "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completionHandler'" at the let task line when I try this

Comment: @Nouman Add `@escaping` in the `calculateRate` method's signature. Added the code above.

Comment: This works to print the value of results, but to actually use the values Can I do something like var ArrayResults = calculateRate(value: codesToConvert) {(results)?

Comment: What you can do is create `var arrayResults` outside of the function call or the class level and assign `results` to it inside the `closure`. I've updated the code for that.

Comment: Hi, I have copied exactly as you said. But when I print arrayResults it is empy?

Comment: Where are you printing it? Print it after you've received the closure is called. Otherwise you'll get it empty.

Comment: i'm doing it in the viewdidload after the calculateRate function is called and closed, i'm printing arrayResults and I get "[:]"

Comment: You won't get it there. It is an async call. Where are you actually using it?

Comment: I'll be using it to populate tableview later. I just like to have all the variables ready at the top before

Comment: You can’t get everything ready in viewDidLoad. It’s an api call. You’ll get the data only when the response is received. Call tableView.reloadData() after arrayResults = results inside the closure.